# MATLAB Legend Groups

Tags: matlab, plot, legend, figure

I'm using MATLAB to plot some data. I would like to create the legend so that it divides information into two types, say Type1 and Type2.
Each type of data has several specific lines of data which i am plotting.
Suppose that:

- Type1 data has line1 and line2
- Type2 data has line1 and line2 and line3

This would make a 5 line plot. Now for the legend i can do something like:

```matlab
legend('Type1: line1','Type1: line2','Type2: line1', ...
       'Type2: line2','Type2: line3');
```

But that repeats the 'Types' and the best way would be something that would look like:

(final legend output)

- Type1:

  - line1
  - line2
- Type2:

  - line1
  - line2
  - line3

Thanks a lot. Hope you can help with my first question here :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to have a look at [LEGENDFLEX](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2011/06/24/flexible-legends/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+mathworks%2Fpick+%28File+Exchange+Pick+of+the+Week%29) that you can download from the [Matlab File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31092)